# Swift xcode dynamically adding text inputs in view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview

I am relatively new to swift and have been used to a JavaScript environment so correct me if it is not possible, but is there a way to dynamically add rows of text inputs and thus data in the form of a nested dictionary, from the view via a button?

I am looking to create an object with no set constraints on the limitations of data.

Essentially the object would be structured as:

```
"Object1": ["row1":[desc: "desc1", option: "option1"]]
```

and when a user adds a row through a UIButton:

```
"Object1": ["row1":[desc: "desc1", option: "option1"], "row2": [desc: "desc2", option: "option2"]]
```

and so on....

[Image example of what I am looking to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4Ury.png)

Thank you for any input provided.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Parsing the dictionary? Programmatically adding UITextFields? Perhaps putting them in a scrollview? Perhaps programmatically adding constraints? As you can see, there are a lot of steps to what you want to do. Please try to do it yourself first and then ask a specific question about a specific challenge. I know for a fact that a few of those challenges already have answers here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the feedback of Will M I did overthink this again and came up with another solution:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let xPos : CGFloat = 0
    var yPos : CGFloat = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func press(sender: AnyObject) {

        yPos += 22
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, 100, 20)
        tf.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.view.addSubview(tf)

    }

}
```

Here is a screenshot of what the result looks like I hope this helps you!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsF8F.jpg

The black things are textfields

Comment: I don't understand the loop part of the answer. Where is the loop supposed to run? If you run it every time the button is tapped, then you are creating the textfields over and over again. If it runs outside of the button action, then it isn't creating the textfields in response to the button being pressed.

Comment: It's because you want as many textfields as the times the button is pressed. You could just say in your button pressed code: counter++ and then call a function createTextfields() which will execute the for-loop.

Comment: cant you just add a text field when the button is pressed instead of using a loop?

Comment: Yes, you could do that also. But you have to store your y-coordinates somewhere and change them everytime the button is pressed.

Comment: so every time you press the button, you increment the loop counter `i`, and then create `i` textfields. So the first time you call it you create 1 textfield, then the next time you call it, you create 2 textfields, one of which is on top of the other textfield, and then the third time you call it, you create 3 text fields, two of which are on top of the previous 2 textfields, so at this point you have 3 textfields stacked on top of each other in the first spot, 2 stacked on top of each other in the second spot, and then 1 textfield in the third spot.

Comment: I didn't overthink it like that. Thanks for keeping me clear... Sorry for the wrong answer.

Comment: thanks for taking a stab at this. I appreciate getting the conversation started. Yes I suppose the other issue to bear in mind is that the Xcode storyboard would need to know where to place the new text field or row.

Comment: @WillM this is my new solution I hope you think this is better!